# Using pulp from pypy

Tags: pypy

I've written a simulator in python and I use Pypy to speed it up. 
I need the Pulp module for integer programming, which is not supported by Pypy 
as far as I can say (http://pypy.org/compat.html).

Is there any clean way to use pulp from Pypy? A python wrapper of some sort, or even a way to call a python script externally and get the results?

-Many thanks

Comment: That it's not listed on pypy.org as explicitly supported doesn't mean a thing. If it's pure Python, it will work unless it relies on implementation details (which is rather hard to do in Python). If it's using C extensions that happen to use only the subset of the CPython API which PyPy supports, it will also work. You may want to re-research that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading delnan's comment, I realized that pypy could not find pulp because it did not know where to look for it. It was complaining:

from pulp import *

ImportError: No module named pulp

Adding the line

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PuLP-1.4.8-py2.7.egg/pulp')
from pulp import *

did the trick and now it seems to work.

Interestingly, running pulp with pypy is twice slower than with normal python. I suspect its the startup cost for the JIT.